# Drunk/Damned mechanics: how do they interact?

Tags: werewolv.es

The question revolves around Damned appearing as a status added to a player rather than being part of a role.

Can a Drunk be Damned?

Can a Drunk sober up into a Damned role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drunk sobering is manually handled by the game moderator, so in theory they can be sobered up into anything.

Damned is a player aura, and can be applied to any role in the game.